# How to find the remains date of a month from a date?

Tags: c#

I have a date '2015-01-25'. How to get the remains date of Jan 2015. Is there any built in function to achieve this in c#
remains days ie, '2015-01-26','2015-01-27','2015-01-28','2015-01-29','2015-01-30','2015-01-31' etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "the remains date"? And do you actually have this as a `DateTime`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, ya '2015-01-25' is a dateTime date

Comment: And "the remains date"? The number of days left in the month? Including or excluding the date itself? Note how you've got different answers understanding your question differently, which suggests your question is unclear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find remaining days till next month, then you can add a day to the current `DateTime` in loop and check if the month of the new `DateTime` is same with yours. If the new `DateTime` met the  condition, then add it to the list. If not, then break the loop.

You will use `DateTime.AddDays()` method which returns a new `DateTime` that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.

```
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 25);

var remainedDateTimesToNextMonth = new List<DateTime>();
var nextDay = myDateTime;

while(true)
{
    nextDay = nextDay.AddDays(1);
    if (nextDay.Month == myDateTime.Month)
    {
        remainedDateTimesToNextMonth.Add(nextDay);
    }
    else break;
}
```

And int the result there would be six item inside `remainedDateTimesToNextMonth` list:

> `2015-01-26`,`2015-01-27`,`2015-01-28`,`2015-01-29`,`2015-01-30`,`2015-01-31`

Answer (score 1):

Get Today

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
```

Get the first day of next month

```
var firstDayNextMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);
```

Create a list of the days between today and first day of next month (Enumerable.Range) Loop through the list and turn them into dates (Select) by adding each int to today

```
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, firstDayNextMonth.Subtract(today).Days + 1)
                      .Select(d => today.AddDays(d))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Please update your answer with more details so it'll be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)` to get total days in months, and subtract the current day of month.

```
DateTime someDate = new DateTime(2015,1,25);
var remaining = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015, 1) - someDate.Day;
```

Then you know the amount of remaining days for that given month, and can set up remaining dates in a list using an for loop.

```
List<DateTime> remainingDays = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 1; i <= remaining; i++)
{
    remainingDays.Add(someDate.AddDays(i));
}
```